# Override html blue font color in Jupyter markdown cell using custom.css

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

I have  several of these following Jupyter markdown cells

*Some text in markdown cell*

which is forced to have a blue font color using html:

```
<font color='blue'> Some text in markdown cell </font>
```

I want to override this blue font color using custom.css

the element which I need to change was the following in my custom.css

```
div.text_cell_render{
     margin:0
}
.rendered_html pre code {
     color: #444 !important;
     font-family: monospace;
}
```

This did not work despite the *!important* appended to the color for override.
I am a css novice. How can I achieve this blue font color override.

Comment: What happens if you target ```font``` selector with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should overwrite it,

html:

```
<div class="selector"><font color="blue">hello</font></div>
```

and the css to target it:

```
.selector font {
    color: red!important;
}
```

Comment: There are several markdown cells which come predefined with the html rendered blue font color . I do not want to modify each of them by adding what you suggested *<div class="selector"*, hence this solution will not work.

Comment: @OzoohaOzooha but you do not need to make all these changes, you only need to get the parent selector once and use ```font``` selector with it. In your example you do not have font in your css selected.

Comment: Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ycgej516/

Comment: @OzoohaOzooha, I believe you are confused about the example set up, you don't need to include any additional html, you just need to select your parent correctly and use font as in my example, those are just dummy classes, set as an example. You understand?